# iMac and HDMI display - not turning off properly

Tags: imac, display, hdmi

I'm using iMac on my work and when i said to my boss that i need 2nd display for work he ordered it and it arrived. Philips Gioco 27" But that display has only VGA and HDMI ports, no DVI. So we bought adapter Mini Display Port to HDMI and connected 2nd monitor to my iMac. Everything seems working fine but when i turn off 2nd display (by pressing power button on it)my mac still thinks that display is turned on and not collapsing desktop area. When i turn 2nd display on it blinks (like normal with 2nd display). Is there a way how to make desktop area collapse when turning off 2nd display?

Comment: Did you try using system preferences ?

Comment: ofc i did try to use